# Does REVERT work when stored procedure is executed from another user?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have these two stored procedures, and `Sales.spExec1` calls `dbo.spExec2`.

When I try to REVERT in the 2nd stored procedure, it doesn't go back to `original_login()`.

Does this mean that `REVERT` works within a stored procedure? It does revert when I call it in `Sales.spExec1`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.spExec1 
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT SUSER_SNAME()  -- 'MyDomain\Bob.Smith'
    PRINT original_login() -- 'MyDomain\Bob.Smith'

    EXECUTE AS USER = 'TempUser';
    EXEC dbo.spExec2

    REVERT;

    /* REVERT works in SP where initial EXECUTE AS USER ran */
    print SUSER_SNAME()  -- 'MyDomain\Bob.Smith'
    print original_login() -- 'MyDomain\Bob.Smith'
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spExec2
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT SUSER_SNAME()  -- 'TempUser'
    PRINT original_login() -- 'MyDomain\Bob.Smith'

    REVERT;

    /* REVERT did not work */
    print SUSER_SNAME()   -- Still `TempUser'
    print original_login()
END;
GO
```

Comment: Most SQL Server clients use connection-pooling so that might complicate things. What happens if you use the `REVERT WITH COOKIE` version instead?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Wouldn't I need to pass the @cookie if using `REVERT WITH COOKIE`?

Comment: Well, yes - that's the point.

Comment: @dai: Even if I send it as a parameter, it doesn't seem to work. I get the following error: 

"Can only use the 'No Revert' or 'Cookie' options with the 'Execute As' statement at the adhoc level."

Comment: Although I can't find a good reference for it, I think the gist is that when you `EXEC dbo.spExec2` the server determines the execution context for the new SP. It will be executed as `'TempUser'` and there is no other context that `revert` can access. When `dbo.spExec2` exits there is an implicit `revert`, but since it never used `EXECUTE AS USER` it has no effect. `Sales.spExec1` then continues with its stack of execution contexts and can `revert` to go back to the initial context.

Comment: I'm curious what you are doing that would require any of this.

Comment: @HABO: that's what I've noticed. The odd thing is that `original_login()` is still the initial user that began execution. I just can't revert to it.

Comment: [`ORIGINAL_LOGIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/original-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) says: "Returns the name of the login that connected to the instance of SQL Server." That's a connection property that won't change regardless of `execute as`, `revert`, executing nested stored procedures and functions, ... .

Answer (score 2):

This is documented here:

> REVERT can be specified within a module such as a stored procedure or user-defined function, or as a stand-alone statement. When specified inside a module, **REVERT is applicable only to EXECUTE AS statements defined in the module**.

[REVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Even a dynamic SQL nested batch doesn't allow REVERT to change the current identity that the batch was started with, eg

```
create user alice without login

select user_name()
execute as user='alice'

exec('select user_name();revert;select user_name()')

revert
select user_name()
```

outputs

```
-----------
dbo

(1 row affected)


------------
alice

(1 row affected)


------------
alice

(1 row affected)


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbo

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. The odd thing is that `Original_login()` will return the login that originated the initial SP call, but I can't revert to it.

Comment: original_login() returns the identity used to connect to SQL Server.  "Returns the name of the login that connected to the instance of SQL Server." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/original-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16